# How can I install Ubuntu's 10.10 kernel I Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: wireless, upgrade, kernel

I did use Ubuntu 10.10 for a long time, and now I replaced it with Ubuntu 12.10, every thing works great, but I do have one little problem, which is with my wireless card.

On Ubuntu 10.10, it worked PERFECTLY, and it even worked better than in windows 7, so I was very happy with Ubuntu 10.10, but, like I said, after installing 12.10, my wireless card doesn't work any more, so I heard that KERNELS are the reason for that.

Are kernels the reason for my wireless not working now? If yes then please teach me how to remove my current kernels and install 10.10 kernels.

---

I went to -Additional Drivers- and i found something very weird i took picture and this is what it look like

[image]

"apply changes" Button NOT active so i can't install driver :(

anyway... my Wireless card is WL-138g v2 (remember on Ubuntu 10.10 it was WORKING 100% normally and FREE i did NOT pay for it driver)

so... now what shall i do ? it is saying in picture // Using Non-Free firmware for linux kernel drivers from linux-firmware-nonfree (proprietary) //

BTW  i did "rfkill list" but NO-thing appear under that command.

Comment: This appears to be an annoying PITA Broadcom b43 wireless card. It's kinda hard to get it to work, and it wasn't working in 10.10 by default - you must have taken actions your own. Share the whole story please. Please post the output of `dmesg | grep b43` and `ls -al /lib/firmware/b43` and the Device vendor/product ids: `lsusb` for USB, `lspci -nn` for PCI.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it is missing kernel modules for your wireless card. It is though not a reason to downgrade to older kernels.

Try using the 'Additional Drivers' software (used to be installed by default earlier) to search for a suitable driver. It will do the rest of the job for you.

It may also be useful to make sure it is not blocked by the system or hardware switch. To check this, execute:

`rfkill list`

To remove of Software lock, execute:

`rfkill unblock <device>`

Comment: @user80547, did this solve your problem? please, let us know.

Comment: uhhh... i found solution for my problem it's very simple i just did :  sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer THIS FIX MY PROBLEM

Answer (score 1):

uhhh... i found solution for my problem it's very simple i just did:
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer ---THIS FIX MY PROBLEM---

BUT dont forget to REBOOT machine, you have to restart you computer after boot in you see wireless work normally.
anyway... thank you guys for help.